# How I can edit a PHP file from another file, like the Wordpress install.php file?

Tags: php, content-management-system, fopen

I'm trying to create an installation script for my CMS but I don't know how...

I want my script to set the `$var` in `config.php` to the entered value.

Like:

```
<?php
$file = config.php
$file_handle = fopen($file, "rw");

fwrite($file_handle, "$settings1 = ".$_POST['settings1']);

fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Is this work or I'm using the bad way? Because I tried it and it doesn't work...

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: Aside from being vulnerable to quite possibly the worst kind of injection, this looks fine. However you may want to put a little more work into defining "doesn't work". My crystal ball is in the shop.

Comment: This code, even if it did work, would completely overwrite the original file with your one "settings" line and produce a syntactically invalid (e.g. fatal error on load) php file.

Comment: It just always rewrite at the same line, and the settings are entered in the file in group of 5-6... (5-steps installation)

Comment: @Christ. it'd write out ` = postvaluehere`, as it's using double quotes, an undefined `$settings1`. `config.php` is unquoted as well, so this code wouldn't even run in the first place.

Comment: Do !NOT! save code to php file directly from POST. oh and you probably forgot to put `config.php` in quotes

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to put `config.php` in quotes... What I need to do before and what is the best method? Else, I will use a database to store settings and `config.php` only for MySQL login information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method to doing this is parsing the configuration file into a variable, parse it and change the settings from the parsed data and then re-write the file back to the file overwriting the old one.

If this is your own cms and you are creating the system, I would go with either an array config like $settings['key'] = $value; or you could also do ini files and use the built in functions of php to parse and then re-write the data.

This is the approach I've used for a long time and it works for me.

**Example**

Here is an example usage for Zend Framework component Zend_Config_Writer: (http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.config.writer.introduction.html)

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('config.ini',
                          null,
                          array('skipExtends'        => true,
                                'allowModifications' => true));

// Modify a value
$config->production->hostname = 'foobar';

// Write the config file
$writer = new Zend_Config_Writer_Ini(array('config'   => $config,
                                       'filename' => 'config.ini'));
$writer->write();
```

They have components for ini, xml, yaml and native php arrays. Would be wise to either incorporate it into your cms or research the methods they use to do so.

Hope that helps,

Jay

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? This approach is very interessting for me... I had in head to create an array like `$settings = array(1 => "value", 2 => "value2", etc...);`...

Comment: Is there a way to write to it with another function? And does the file need to exist or it will be created?

Comment: I would seperate it into two methods create and edit, in the create function if your going to use Zend's packages use Zend_Config to create a new config object then pass it to the the write method. In the edit method load the file that already exists and update the settings then pass it to the write method. The writer will create a new file if one doesn't exist. If you don't want to use the Zend packages I would look at their source code for the format you wish to use and copy the functionality into your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/config.php', "$settings1 = ".clean($_POST['settings1']), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

And be aware of the permission.

Comment: :D Save code to php file directly from POST? :DDD This is just awesome idea!

Comment: I need to CHMOD 777 before and 755 after?

Comment: The apache user should have write permission on the file.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty.
File you need to edit:

```
$i_am_a_var = [I AM A PLACE HOLDER NUMBER 4];
```

Here is the installation script:

```
$c=file_get_content('file_to_edit.php');
$c=str_replace('[I AM A PLACE HOLDER NUMBER 4]',"'zimbabue the new value'",$c);
file_put_content('file_to_edit.php',$c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use .ini files for configuration. They are exteremely easy to read (have a look at [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) for instance). Writing them is a bit more difficult but I still think it's easier than what you are trying to do.

Also you can use a JSON file with json_encode() and json_decode() for such purposes too since for them you have finished functions to read and write such files.

Comment: And if I want to write content to it, how in PHP?